# Php queries - Entry Processes

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, backend

Here is the situation: I have an app that makes a request every 3 seconds to the server via a PHP file in the "public_html".
The issue arise when I have 20 devices with the app running simultaneously, that means I made 400 requests per minute.
Worst of all I get this message:

> "You have reached entry processes (number of simultaneously running php and cgi scripts, as well as cron jobs and shell sessions) limit XXXXX times"

I also see: Entry processes: 20/20 in the cpanel.

I am not sure if the huge number of request is causing the problem or if I am misunderstanding something?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What does PhpMyAdmin have to do with this? That's a utility for doing manual queries against a database, it has nothing to do with devices calling an API.

Comment: Related: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61286/how-to-find-out-what-is-causing-entry-process-limit?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa